# Особенности диапазона типа int

Tags: c, int

Почему выдает видимое число? При введении чисел большего количества значений int и как? Желательно подробно обьяснить, почему оно попадает в else!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "math.h"
#include "locale.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "windows.h"
int main() {
    int num;

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    printf("\nВведіть число: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > 0) {
        printf("Ти ввів додатнє число!");
    }
    else if (num == 0) {
        printf("Ти ввів число 0!");
    }
    else {
        printf("Ти ввів від'ємне число!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Проверял диапазон типа int и заметил интересную фигуру.

Comment: Вы бы все-таки ввели текст корректно... Какое конкретно значение вы вводите?

Comment: больше диапазона, 380932743298472

Comment: При впихивании этого числа в 32 бита получается число -791085656, что приводит к выполнению блока else

Comment: а почему выходит такое число?

Comment: Потому что число 380932743298472 записывается в двоичной системе как 1010110100111010011010000110110001111110110101000, отбрасываем старшие биты, которые не влезают в 32 бита — остаётся 11010000110110001111110110101000, а так как старший бит обозначает знак числа и в данном случае он имеет значение 1, то в итоге получаются, что вот эти оставшиеся биты соответствуют отрицательному числу -791085656

Comment: О каких особенностях речь? Никаких особых особенностей тут нет.

Comment: Осталось добавить что переполнение в `scanf` -  неопределённое поведение и результат может быть любым или результата может не быть вовсе.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

С диапазоном всё в порядке, у это скорее всего visual studio буянит на счёт Си функций. Если они вам настолько принципиальны, то посмотрите в настройках проекта, или просто используйте iostream с функциями cin >>, cout <<

Comment: «С диапазоном всё в порядке» — нет

Comment: прошу прощения, не до конца понял смысл вопроса
если так, то при переполнении числа в бинарном виде лишняя часть отсекается

Comment: я спрашивал, про работу функции инт во время выхода числа из диапазона